# Restore directory to previous state

Tags: rsync, backup, file-copy

I have an approximately 1TB directory with subdirectories `dir1`. I have made an `rsync` backup copy `dir1.back`.

How can I efficiently restore `dir1` to the state of `dir1.back` - that is, replace files in `dir1` with those of `dir1.back` if they've change and deleting any new files in `dir1`? Given its large size, `cp`/`rsync` of the entire `dir1.back` is highly infeasible.

If I'm not mistaken, this *might* be possible using `rsync --check-sum`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reverse the RSYNC. So swap around dir1 and dir1.back then add the delete flag to ensure it removes files as appropriate to make sure it properly syncs and not just ignore files that weren't present in dir1 originally.

```
rsync -avz --delete dir1.bak/ dir1/
```

Comment: and how about reversing dir.bak to previous state before rsync?! 